# MYSQL incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql

I'm having this issue, tried to google it but i didn't figured it out... , I need to convert it to mysql format.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATAIN, "%y %m %d") from schema.table;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

But i get this error and i'm not figuring it out what's wrong with it. I tried to replace "'" and '/' too but nothing.

```
   # Level  Code    Message
Warning 1411    Incorrect datetime value: '10/05/2021' for function str_to_date
Warning 1411    Incorrect datetime value: '27/04/2021' for function str_to_date
Warning 1411    Incorrect datetime value: '10/05/2021' for function str_to_date
Warning 1411    Incorrect datetime value: '10/05/2021' for function str_to_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your current string date format , seems like date format should be like this :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATAIN, '%d/%m/%Y') from schema.table;
```

also it should be enclosed with single quotes

Comment: Omg thank you what a stupid error i got. Thanks again it worked.